# Android requestfactory min API level

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gwt

We built an android application that communicates with App Engine via Requestfactory.
We seem to have ironed out all the wrinkles as far as the 2.2+ API levels are concerned - including both "debug" and "export" modes (i.e. all the ProGuard issues).

When testing the same binary APK on a 2.1 device we get the exception:
`The RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run for the com.*** RequestFactory type`

As I mentioned, we resolved this issue for the "debug" and "export" modes already.
We don't use C2DM at all (which would have required 2.2+).

How can we support Android 2.1 if at all ?